# Error: "Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'" when using Autograd and Scipy Interpolation(bisplrep)

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, autograd

I am trying to differentiate a function respect to a matrix, which is an input, whith the "grad" function of Autograd (I have to use this function mandatorily).

The problem is that, for getting the output, first I have to make an interpolation with those matrix values apart from other inputs.

For this I have to use scipy implementation in Autograd (import autograd.scipy.special as sc), bisplrep in particular. This function returns a list (tck) with several elements, nodes, degree of the interpolation.. and when I use auotgrad I get the title error.

I have read a lot and, in fact, I think that it is because the arrays are float64 type and the degrees of the interpolation are ints instead of int64 (every element should be double?).

Despite this, I don't know how to fix this, as making tck[3:5]=np.int64(tck[3:5]) does not work.

Example below where venc and mon are float64 arrays:

```
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(venc, mon)

tck = sc.scipy.interpolate.bisplrep(xx, yy , matrix, kx= sc.scipy.int64(1), ky=sc.scipy.int64(3)) 
    
def spline_iv(exp, mon, tck):    
    iv = sc.scipy.interpolate.bisplev(exp, mon, tck)
    return iv

def imp_vol1(exp, mon):
    return spline_iv(exp, mon, tck)#, kx=1, ky=3) )
   
value = mc_value(option_type, S0, K, r, T, I, N, imp_vol1, q=0)
```

Lastly I use Autograd to a function where the previous code is inside and the "matrix" in the 7th position:

```
vega = grad(compute_mc_value, 7)
v_grad1 = vega('C', S0, 11020.1, 0.06, 0.3, 1000, 50, matrix, venc, mon)
```

And I get the error of the title, due to bisplrep:

Thanks

Comment: You should provide a [MRVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Done. Sorry and thanks.

Comment: The "Minimal" and "Reproducible" in MRVE are important. Sometimes, when you minimalize your example the error disappears (divide and conquer effect); if not, "reproducible" will encourage answers. Currently, NameErrors on matrix, venc, mon, (others probably). Writing a reproducible example may even trigger the magic of the [rubber duck](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/); in your case, maybe mon and venc are arrays of objects and not float64 as you thought?